# Gitlab artifacts creation fails when shell commands are used directly

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab

I'm facing a very weird issue in configuring CI with gitlab.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have following definition

```
pylint:
  before_script:
    - echo "Skipping before script"
  stage: prerequisites
  image: docker.artifactory.com/spark_build:1.7
  script:
    - mkdir ./pyspark/pylint
    - pylint ./fs/programs/pyspark/> ./pyspark/pylint/overall.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./pyspark/pylint
    expire_in: 1 day
  tags:
   - kubernetes
```

This Job fails with a very generic message

`ERROR: Job failed: error executing remote command: command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 1`

Now what I did is I put the `mkdir` and `pylint` commands in a bash script and executed that in script section like below :

```
 script:
    - sh bin/execute-pylint.sh
```

This works like a charm.

So my question is what is the difference between these two approaches ? If possible, Can somebody point me to some docs where such behavior is documented.

Comment: Please add the logs before the error too. Concluding from other issues the line before the one you have posted seems to be the interesting part. See [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2577) or [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34419)

Comment: @secustor well that's the problem. There are no errors before that. I can very well see PyLint's message `No Configuration found, using default configurations` and then the error message.